# How to pass parameters to JSON Action with Struts2 JQuery Grid plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, struts2, grid

I am using the struts2 Jquery-Grid plugin but couldn't find how to pass parameters to the JSON Action.

There's this diagram: [Grid diagram](http://www.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery/struts2_jquery_grid.png)

I have parameters (search ID's) sent to Grid Action (as in the diagram) but how do I continue passing them down to the grid.jsp and to JSON Data Action, which retrieves Data from the DB based on these parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: The diagram is not correct. The JSP creates a page for the client, the client then holds onto this page, the page makes calls with javascript to the two actions which spit out json and the client is then able to update the grid accordingly. The action should not forward its request to a jsp or you would get a new page, not update the one you have.

Comment: So what should the Grid action (first action) forward to if not to the jsp page with the grid?

Comment: An action as a concept bundles together the initial request, processing and rendering and the sending of the result back to the client. With that out of the way Grid Action would be better named "Grid Action Class" same goes for the other two action classes. Following the existing diagram: the user request makes its way to the Grid Action Class which prepares the initial data for the Grid. Then forwards that to a jsp which returns a web page to the user (arrow from grid.jsp) back to user/browser. The user/browser then invoke the JSON Data Action and JSON edit action directly.

Comment: I understand what you said. But I still don't understand how to pass the parameters. Let me give you an example: index.jsp page with several selection parameters, when user submits the form, its forwarded to GridAction with the parameters. THOSE parameters have to be passed on to the grid.jsp, and then to the JSON Action (for retrieval from database). Am I right so far? If so, how should I pass these parameters from Grid Action to the grid.jsp and then to the Json Action?

Comment: Well you could be right but to be clear.  ..."THOSE parameters have to be passed on to the grid.jsp"... and then this goes back to the browser. The browser invokes the JSON Data/Edit actions directly via JS ajax calls, the actions serialize their data into JSON and return it to the browsers ajax call. Do you know jquery by any chance? Is your database a mysql db? If so I may have an example that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I exactly needed the same thing recently so here's what I did.

```
<s:url id="gridaction" action="remoteurl" escapeAmp="false">
    <s:param name="param1">value1</s:param>
    <s:param name="param2">value2</s:param>
    <s:param name="param2" value=%{value3}/>
</s:url>
<sj:grid href=%{remoteurl}.../>
```

Hope so this may help.